# callback function as a module.export parameter

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Can anyone explain what does the `callback()` function do in the code below? and where does this callback function come from?

**index.js**

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var i18n = require('./lib/i18n');

var options = {
  stage: 'options:post:configuration'
};

/**
 * postprocess
 * @param  {Object}   params
 * @param  {Function} callback
 */
module.exports = function (params, callback) {
  'use strict';

  var grunt = params.grunt;

  grunt.verbose.subhead('Running:'.bold, '"assemble-contrib-i18n"');
  grunt.verbose.writeln('Stage:  '.bold, '"' + params.stage + '"\n');

  var opts = params.assemble.options.i18n;
  grunt.verbose.writeln('Options: '.bold, require('util').inspect(opts));

  if (opts) {
    var o = {};
    var data = opts.data;
    var templates = opts.templates;
    var languages = opts.languages;

    if (templates) {
      o.templates = templates;
    }

    if (languages) {
      o.languages = languages;
    }
//data = path to a json file containing a list of languages, o = templates & languages
    var pages = i18n(data, o);

    grunt.verbose.writeln('Pages: '.bold, require('util').inspect(pages));
    params.assemble.options.pages = _.extend({}, (params.assemble.options.pages || {}), pages);

  }

  callback();
};

module.exports.options = options;
```

and the place where this `index.js` file is been used is in this gruntfile.js file

```
  "with-plugin": {
    options: {
      plugins: ['./index.js'],
      i18n: {
        data: ['test/fixtures/data/i18n.json'],
        templates: ['test/fixtures/templates/*.hbs']
      }
    },
    dest: 'test/actual/with-plugin/',
    src: '!*.*'
  },
```

so what is the callback function here?

Answer (score 0):

The function being defined (which accepts a callback as a param) is the value that is imported when a script `requires` this module. So the callback is provided by the calling script:

```
require('someModule')(someParams, myCallback);
// which is the same as:
var func = require('someModule');
func(someParams, myCallback);
```

In the code you provided, the callback does nothing special, it is simply executed at the end of the function.

Comment: hi, I have updated my post. can you elaborate a bit more what's the callback function in this case?